# Track amount of webservice calls by same user

Tags: c#

I'm currently developing a web-service based application that needs to track how often a specific client called it in a certain time frame. The service is set up in a way where the client calls one specific url, which triggers one specific function; the service does whatever it needs to do and spits out a response that gets interpreted into a webpage-like UI by the client.

On that page, there is a retry button that calls the same link again, which restarts the application from the very beginning. This cannot be changed, I have no control over the post parameters and the entire application gets restarted every time.

It would look something like this:

```cs
//user calls www.imawebservice.com/dosomething.svc/somemethod

public class dosomething
{
    public Response somemethod()
    {
        //do things
        int counter = GetCounterSomehow(); // help please
        if(counter > someLimit) return Response("go away");
        counter++;
        Response response = new Response(
            new Link("www.imawebservice.com/dosomething.svc/somemethod"))
        return response;
    }
}
```

Except for a database, how can I save simple key-value pairs between web service self-calls, at best natively in C#? If this is a timeout based process, even better.

Edit: This data is not supposed to be kept for long. This is a simple counter that gets discarded after a certain time period or based on a certain condition in the flow of the service. All that is needed is a C# mechanism to essentially cache a simple key-value pair in between service calls.

Edit 2: Added a reason for why Im counting into the code for more clarity.

Comment: what's wrong with a database? But you could of course use a text file (e.g. JSON, XML, CSV format) to store data, or a NoSQL style database (e.g. mongoDB or similar) maybe

Comment: Does it have to be persistent or would caching like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2 work?

Comment: You can mix Log4net and sql insertion

Comment: @ADyson Database calls for a single counter seem like overkill to me personally, especially when it is supposed to be cleaned up after a certain time period (like a session would)
Text file based stuff wont work as well because of our server setup

Comment: @MattLuccasPhaureJensen I would rather avoid aspnet

Comment: @taktak I cant install external libraries like that

Comment: What about a rest api that fill a json file? you can crud on it and get every elements you need and query it.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/ allows you to do it without using aspnet but I see now that you cannot use external libraries.

Comment: What's "overkill" about adding this data to a database? If you are collecting this data, you are collecting it for a reason and plan to use it somehow in the future. Having it in a database means that the data is in a known location, is easily queryable, and can store related metadata. For example, what if management now wants to know what time of day the action is being called the most often?

Comment: Why on earth can't you install external libraries? They're just NuGet packages. You can barely build a functioning application these days without 3rd party libraries. Even the default MVC/web API templates in visual studio add quite a few immediately. Gone are the days (I thought) when management got scared of installing things they hadn't written themselves

Comment: I don't think a database is particularly overkill really. Although something like a cloud based event capture / hub type service might work for this kind of bulk data, especially if throughput is very high. Not sure why you want to clear the data after a session though? How are you going to analyse long term trends or look for performance issues etc? These days, analytical data is big business...

Comment: @ADyson I dont want to analyse anything, and this data is not supposed to be kept. I want to kick the client out of the application into a different default case if they try it too often in a row without success (please dont ask why). Nothing more.

Comment: @ADyson I cant install 3rd party packages because our company policy say so. This has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: It does, because using one might help achieve your aim. I would be astonished if your company's apps aren't riddled with 3rd party code already (for the reasons I already mentioned). If not, they're just holding themselves back for no sensible reason. You should probably mention it. It's a policy stuck in the 1990s.  But anyway why don't you want to analyse that data retrospectively? If you have a client who is persistently misbehaving and getting kicked out then it might be useful to know that so you can take further action, e.g. ban them or educate them, or whatever. Short-sighted.

Comment: Anyhow, good luck with your project however you decide to go about it. I mention these things in a spirit of helpfulness, not as criticism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "external libraries" doesn't include standard .Net libraries you could reference System.Runtime.Caching, and do something similar to this. There are overloads which allow you to use [time based expiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.set?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_Caching_MemoryCache_Set_System_String_System_Object_System_DateTimeOffset_System_String_).

```
   public class dosomething
    {
    public Response somemethod()

        ObjectCache cache = System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default;  
         int counter = (int?)cache["userId"] ?? 0;

        if (counter>=1000) return; //example max calls threshold

        cache.Set("userId", counter +1, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(1));   


        Response response = new Response(
            new Link("www.imawebservice.com/dosomething.svc/somemethod"))
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lixyna you should be aware that MemoryCache is app domain specific. If this is running on multiple endpoints, the state is not shared across those nodes. That is the advantage of an out of process backing store, like a database

Comment: At least from what I can see right now with limited testing, this works exactly as I wanted. Perfect :) 
I will keep the endpoint thing in mind and see if this makes problems during user acceptence, but I dont think it's an issue.